# SpriteKit Swift 2.0 Game: Buttons & Nodes across multiple Scenes

Tags: swift, button, audio, sprite-kit, scene

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 and am brand new to Swift.

I have a Scene with a button at the top that plays and pauses music.
How do I make this button available across multiple Scenes? I would like this button to appear on all of my scenes (menu, level select, game...)

game view controller code:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("gametrack1", ofType: "mp3")        
if let filePath = filePath {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        do{
            try AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }catch
        { print("error") }
    }
```

and the Scene that holds the Pause/Play button, along with what to do when it's pressed is:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayPauseOverlay: SKScene {    

var buttonPlayPause = SKSpriteNode()    

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    if musicPlaying == true
    { buttonPlayPause = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonPause") } else
    { buttonPlayPause = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonPlay") }
    buttonPlayPause.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    buttonPlayPause.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - 50)
    self.addChild(buttonPlayPause)


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if buttonPlayPause.containsPoint(location) {

            if musicPlaying == true{
                //we want to pause and show a play button
                musicPlaying = false
                buttonPlayPause.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttonPlay")
                print("pause")
                AudioPlayer.pause()
            }else{
                musicPlaying = true
                buttonPlayPause.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttonPause")
                print("play")
                AudioPlayer.play()
            }
        }else{ ... }
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

How do I take all of the information in this scene (a working button) and make it available to other scenes without copy paste? How do i overlap two scenes basically? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve is to make the button in the view-controller, either programmatically or in the interface builder. Because all scenes run in the same view-controller. So just drag a button from interface builder, give it some nice layout and connect a function to it in your viewcontroller class.

Then inside that function, run the code to pause/play the audio.

Comment: how do i do this programmatically? i'm getting endless errors. the GameViewController doesn't like SKSpriteNodes (expects UIView?), doesn't have a member "frame," can't use self.addchild(), the touchesbegan function has errors..

Comment: that's becuase SkSpriteNode is a SkScene object, to make a regular button use UIButton. The easiest way is to go to your storyboard, and drag a button your viewcontroller. If you haven't done this before, just look for a tutorial of making a simple one button app. Or if you want to do it programmatically (I shouldn't do it if you don't have to) I can give you a code example.